# Не понимаю, почему крашится?

Tags: java, android

Студия ничего не пишет. При запуске в эмуляторе крашится. Что-то намутил с кнопками. Помогите. Спасибо.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SoundPool sp;
private int sound1;
private int sound2;
private int sound3;
private int sound4;
private int sound5;
private int sound6;
private int sound7;

Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
Button btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    sound1 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound1,1);
    sound2 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound2,1);
    sound3 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound3,1);
    sound4 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound4,1);
    sound5 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound5,1);
    sound6 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound6,1);
    sound7 = sp.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound7,1);
}

public void stopbtn (View view) {

    sp.stop(sound1);
    sp.stop(sound2);
    sp.stop(sound3);
    sp.stop(sound4);
    sp.stop(sound5);
    sp.stop(sound6);
    sp.stop(sound7);

    btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


public void playsound1 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound1,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1, 0f);
}
public void playsound2 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound2,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
public void playsound3 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound3,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
public void playsound4 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound4,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
public void playsound5 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound5,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
public void playsound6 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound6,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
public void playsound7 (View view) {

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    sp.play(sound7,0.1f,0.1f,0,-1,0f);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drum Loops:"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"/>

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:onClick="playsound1"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="2"
            android:onClick="playsound2"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="3"
            android:onClick="playsound3"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="4"
            android:onClick="playsound4"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="5"
            android:onClick="playsound5"
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="6"
            android:onClick="playsound6"
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="7"
            android:onClick="playsound7"
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:onClick="stopbtn"
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Зачем убрал код, который имеет отношение к вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `findViewById();` ищет вьюхи в разметке активити. А оная загружается методом `setContentView`, который вызывается в `onCreate()` методе, вызываемом системой. А метод вы может быть вызван пока не загрузится класс. А в процессе загрузки класса должны сперва инициализироваться его поля.

Т.е. вы пытаетесь инициализировать поля вашего класса гарантированно до того как их можно инициализировать не `null` значением.

**Итого:**

Просто перенесите вызовы `findViewById();` после `setContentView`